# VBA interface: multipe modules with same function names

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface

As I have no keyboard shortcut for putting things in/out of comment in VBA, I made multiple modules with different versions of the same functions (names).

However VBA does not even give me the option to run my currently selected module/subs/functins. I guess I need to delete the "copied" modules first?

[image]

Comment: Function names need to be unique. You cannot have the same function name multiple times even if they are in different modules. VBA does not have namespaces.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: that's not right: you can have the same function/sub name in different modules. But you have to call them together with the modules name, e.g Modul1.GetInput, Modul2.GetInput. Modules behave like "namespaces". https://i.imgur.com/W08npsK.png: this compiles without error